# How to fix Findbugs security warning for 'Potential Path Traversal (File Read)'

Tags: java

I'm getting above warning with 'Method java.io.File reads a file whose location is specified by user input' message after running findbugs in the below code snippet.

```
public void removeFile(String warfileName){
    File warFile = new File(homePath + "/samples/" + warFileName + ".war");
.....
}
```

What would be the best way of fixing this security isssue?

Comment: Check below link. It gives explanation for findbug errors.               http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm

Comment: In this specific case, the documentation is here: http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#PATH_TRAVERSAL_IN

Answer (score 10):

As @Jeet pointed out, one solution is described into the page. Basically, it sugests to use a framework to "normalize" the user input, ie:

```
File file = new File("resources/images/", image); //Weak point
File file = new File("resources/images/", FilenameUtils.getName(image)); //Fix
```

The problem with this solution is that it introduces a dependency to your project (to Apache Commons).

So instead using FilenameUtils.getName, you could try to use java 7 `Files` and `Path`. Probably Path#getFileName() would help to fix the vunerability.

Comment: The two APIs `File.getName()` and `Path.getFilename()` will be added at some point. I did not know about both methods. https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/issues/241

Comment: how can `FilenameUtils.getName(image)` be more secure? isn't that 'location is specified by user input'?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
File file = new File(FilenameUtils.getName(image));
```

Answer (score 0):

or else Path

```
Path target = new File("/home/jt/", 
FilenameUtils.getName(getName())).toPath();
Path source = new File("/home/jt/new/", 
FilenameUtils.getName(getName())).toPath();

Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Where are the closing parenthesis for `File()` method?